# c# multiple server - multiple clients latency

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server

I have customized system. System configuration is below.

I have WinForm Application on Windows 7 P, C#, and .Net 2.0.

It is server-client application. I have multiple server system almost 60 systems. My application create multiple clients to connect each server.

Each clients has sending/receiving backgroundworker. If only one client send multiple commands (25 commands) to only one server, then It tooks 3 secs. However, If each client send multiple commands to each servers, then It tooks 18 secs, not 3 secs.

Is there any reason ?

**Update** 
a PC has Network Card for 4 channel. each channel has connected with 10 mores server controller.

**Edited**
I have solved this issue. The main root cause to implement Server code with BGW(Backgroundworker). I have changed from BGW to thread - receiving and sending function.

I get the fast response with 25 commands for each client. Even I connected 50 clients, I got same time response for whole clients.

Comment: Assuming this is TCP, it should be the connection overhead.

Comment: Yes, It is TCP/IP Connection. Is there any solution to improve the speed ?

Comment: It's most likely your server implementation. But it's impossible to tell way as you just ask in general terms. Hence I'm voting to close the question as it's unanswerable.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM: 15 seconds longer because of the connection overhead? That's unlikely...

Comment: I changed the server implementation from BGW to thread. Then I got fast response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue. The main root cause to implement Server code with BGW(Backgroundworker). I have changed from BGW to thread - receiving and sending function.

I get the fast response with 25 commands for each client. Even I connected 50 clients, I got same time response for whole clients.